# Как посмотреть результат макроподстановки в gcc

Tags: c, макрос

Есть макрос

```
#define DIR_INC(arr) ( {                            \
   int i;                                           \
   for(i=0; sizeof((arr))/sizeof((arr)[0]); i++) {  \
    (arr)[i]++;                                     \
   }                                                \
} )
```

Необходимо посмотреть, что и как сгенерил `gcc`

Попутный вопрос - как увидеть что сгенерил макрогонератор в `gdb`?

Comment: Кстати, у Вас ошибочка. Не написано полностью условие продолжения цикла. Должно быть что-то вроде

`i < sizeof((arr))/sizeof((arr)[0])`

Answer (score 7):

Самый надежный способ - запускаете компилятор с параметром `-E` (это для gcc, для студии - `/E`) - он покажет результат препроцессирования. Я делаю в консоли следующее.

```
gcc filename.c -E > rez.c
```

потом открываю и смотрю.

А gdb - это уже другое дело.

Comment: маленькое дополнение. В сгенерированном коде будет много строк вида `#line число` - это так препроцессор оставляет метки, что бы потом компилятор смог сгенерировать правильно отладочную информацию. Но они помогают разобраться в коде также.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такое писать? Оформите этот код как функцию. Такой макрос может создать вам кучу проблем.
попробуйте на пример скомпилить такое:

```
.....
int i = 0;
......
DIR_INC(arr);
......
```

Comment: Более хорошим примером было бы `int* arr`. Макросы и правда зло, жаль, что в C метапрограммирование не зачаточном уровне.

Comment: Макросы - это очень хорошая штука, если уметь их применять. А плохими их считают те, кто их не понимает, проще ведь так говорить, чем разобраться.